# Django CreateView success_url fails

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have built an address model, address list and create address. My problem is that the create view does not redirect the browser to the success_url. The create view is displayed correctly and upon submit the new address is added to the database but the address does not change. Consequently, the user thinks it failed so clicks submit again. Changing the browser IP address directly will show the address created multiple times. I created a simple project and repeated this code in it and the browser does redirect to the list view as expected. I have also tried overriding get_success_url(self) with no change. I have changed the success_url, again no change. I know this worked early in development but was found to be broke during final testing.

Here is my console output starting with the initial address List View.

```
[13/Apr/2018 12:42:57] "GET /accounts/my_address/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4853
[13/Apr/2018 12:43:01] "GET /accounts/create-address/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5715
[13/Apr/2018 12:43:11] "POST /accounts/create-address/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Apr/2018 12:43:11] "GET /accounts/my_address/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5898
```

The console log says it is doing the right thing but the browser address bar is /accounts/create-address/ instead of /accounts/my_address/

My question is how do I debug this to determine why the browser does not change, i.e .

**models.py**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    """
    Allow an account to have multiple addresses for which one
    must be active. Shipments will be sent to the active address.
    """
    STREET_LENGTH = 128
    CITY_LENGTH = 64
    STATE_LENGTH = 32
    POSTAL_CODE_LENGTH = 10
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(help_text='Select the Active address')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=STREET_LENGTH)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=CITY_LENGTH)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=STATE_LENGTH)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=POSTAL_CODE_LENGTH)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Address
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=Address.STREET_LENGTH, label='Street:',
                         required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
                             attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': 'autofocus'}),)

     postal_code = forms.CharField(max_length=Address.POSTAL_CODE_LENGTH, label='Postal Code:',
                              required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control postal_code'}))

     city = forms.CharField(max_length=Address.CITY_LENGTH, label='City:',
                       required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control city'}))

     state = forms.CharField(max_length=Address.STATE_LENGTH, label='State:',
                        required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control state'}))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_address/', AddressListView.as_view(), name='my_address'),
    path('create-address/', AddressCreateView.as_view(), 
         name="create-address"),
]
```

**views.url**

```
class AddressListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Address
    def get_queryset(self):
        account = self.request.user
        addresses = Address.objects.filter(account=account).order_by('-active')
        return addresses

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddressListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        account = self.request.user
        context['account'] = account
        return context

class AddressCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    """
    View to create new account address
    """
    template_name = "accounts/address_create.html"
    form_class = AddressForm
    model = Address
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:my_address')
    success_message = "Address was added successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Assign the account to the request.user
        """
        form.instance.account = self.request.user
        form.instance.active = False
        return super(AddressCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: This question is not clear. What IP address are you expecting? Why are you on a different one in the first place? And your success_url doesn't reference an IP address anyway, so why would you expect it to change?

Comment: Are you saying that on save you do not get redirected to success_url (note, this is not the IP)?

Comment: If you are making an AJAX request, then your JavaScript has to handle the 302 redirect response.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct the IP address should not change, just the URL. It should redirect to accounts/my_address/ but stays at accounts/create-address/

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was in the HTML file with some leftover AJAX. I was trying somethings out, I had added address_form in the class of form tag of the HTML and an AJAX call was made. Consequently AJAX and HTTP call both occur. I removed address_form from the form tag's class and problem goes away.

```
<form class="form-horizontal address_form" method="post">
```

was changed to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
```

and later was some javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $addressForm = $('.address_form')
  $addressForm.submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      var $formData = $(this).serialize()
      var $endpoint = $addressForm.attr("data-url")
      $.ajax({method: "POST", url: $endpoint, 
         data: $formData, 
         success: handleFormSuccess,
         error: handleFormError,
     })

  })
```